# Testing Automation Tools For .NET

Tags: .net, testing, open-source, automation

I'm trying to find some useful Open Source Testing Automation Tools for use with the .NET framework. I've done a fair bit of research, but unfortunately, most of the tools I have found focus on testing web applications only.

There are 3 types of programs that we run in order to make our software do what it needs to do: We program a service in VB.NET to collect data, we have an AJAX/JavaScript + VB/ASP.NET web application to view the data, and a VB.NET Form-based GUI to edit the data.

I understand that the chances finding a tool that would test all three is slim to nil, but I was not expecting a single tool to cover all of them.

Since the service we run is the most important, I was hoping the Stack Overflow community might have some insight as to what testing automation tools would be particularly useful for VB.NET services. Any information with respect to the GUI or Web Application sides would be a great help as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can test your service with any unit test framework like [NUnit](http://nunit.org/index.php), [MbUnit](http://www.gallio.org/), MSTest, ... .

Your web application like you probably know there many different applications like [Watir](http://wtr.rubyforge.org/), [Watin](http://watin.sourceforge.net/), [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), [SWAT](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ulti-swat/), [Telerik WebUITest Studio](http://www.telerik.com/products/web-testing-tools.aspx).

I'm not familiar with Windows form testing tool; however, I know that Telerik is comming up with one.

Comment: For UI testing (web, WPF, Silverlight, Windows Modern UI/Metro, and WinForms), Microsoft has Coded UI, which is part of Visual Studio.

Comment: Windows forms fuzzer/exerciser - which is super easy to use - https://github.com/SJMakin/FuzzWinForms

Answer (score 3):

[TestComplete.](http://testcomplete.com)

You can definitely use capture-replay to capture and run the test script. But I would suggest that you must at least manually edit your scripts to make them

1. more readable
2. easier to maintain.

The good thing about TestComplete is that it is able to look into your form's properties, capture those properties so that you can refer to those properties by their name, not by just screen coordinates.

Here's [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411190/ui-testing-tool).

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of good tools for testing.

Business Objects - test with [NUnit](http://nunit.org),mbUnit,MSTest

Web testing - [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org) and NUnit or [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/)

Desktop GUI - not sure but you could try pyWinAuto - its a python application but you could use IronPython which is the .NET implementation

Comment: pyWinAuto does not support .NET forms.  Wasn't able to get it to work reliably.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Apis I developed for https://github.com/o2platform/FluentSharp I was able to write tests that cover the 3 scenarios that you mention

See these tests https://github.com/TeamMentor/Dev/tree/master/Source_Code/TM_UnitTests/TeamMentor.UnitTests.QA for a significant number of real-world tests written that way

See also [disable IE visibility while using WatiN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429361/disable-ie-visibility-while-using-watin/27478343#27478343) for an example of an Web Automation test

Answer (score 0):

For load testing you cant beat [Open STA](http://www.opensta.org/)

Answer (score 0):

For unit, integrate and static testing you can using   [Parasoft](http://www.parasoft.com) .

Comment: Could you please add more details about the solution you provide and not only a link?

Comment: @abarisone Parasoft for a .net testing But not open source.
Of course you can use it for a limited time. Try this program can be used to test the quality of programs that can compare.
>
* Static code analysis, data flow analysis, and metrics analysis
* Unit test creation, execution, optimization, and maintenance
* Peer code review process automation, preparation, notification, and tracking
* Use independently or in conjunction with Parasoft Development Testing Platform