# QTP to Jenkins integration help need CI

Tags: maven, testing, jenkins, qtp, jenkins-plugins

We have to run QTP VB Scripts from Jenkins being as a part of CI
Can any one suggest me what is the best way to integrate ?

Advanced thanks
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running Quicktest Pro tests from maven/Jenkins?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446813/running-quicktest-pro-tests-from-maven-jenkins)

Comment: For those who are still looking for some detailed answer,

http://www.testautomationguru.com/executing-qtpuft-scripts-using-jenkins/

Answer (score 3):

Jenkins can run anything you can run from the command line, and you can create QTP [Automation objects](http://www.qtpworld.com/index.php?cid=77) :

```
Dim Application
Set Application = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
Application.Launch 
Application.Visible = True 
Application.Open "testfile", True 

Dim Test
Set Test = Application.Test
Test.Run
```

If you search for `quicktest.application` you will find plenty of examples.

You can start this procedure using a *Windows Batch Command* build step in Jenkins with the [cscript](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cscript_overview.mspx?mfr=true) interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for your help Anders, So should I mention list of test scripts which I want to run in .BAT file ? If I want to see test results in Jenkins is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, the BAT file should contain the commands you wish to run - what you would run in the command prompt on a windows workstation.

To import the test results in Jenkins, they will have to be in a format that Jenkins understand. The format is not very complex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922867/junit-xml-format-specification-that-hudson-supports

Comment: Hi I am connecting JENKINS(machine1) TO QTP (machine2) so I am connecting through Remote desktop connection by using vb script.

Comment: strUser = "K003277" 
strDomain = "PNKUKDEV"
strComputer ="DV01123"
strPassword = "Pork2013" 

Set objSWbemLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator") 
Set objWMIService = objSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(strComputer, _ 
    "root\CIMV2", _ 
    strUser, _ 
    strPassword, _ 
    "MS_409", _ 
    "NTLMDomain:" + strDomain)